# Remove files in folder without removing folders

Tags: powershell

How to remove all files in folder and subfolders without removing folders itself? For example:

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\dummyuser\foldertoclean\subfolders -recurse
```

I was trying with -Include and -Exclude but still havent found solution.

Comment: `Remove-Item -Path path/to/folder/* -Recurse`

Comment: Thank you. This works just like solution posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following easy one-liner:

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\dummyuser\foldertoclean\* -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\dummyuser\foldertoclean -Include `*.*` -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. PowerShell message:
Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.
At line:1 char:103